# Loaded model receives different prediction compared to saved model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, google-colaboratory, joblib

I am trying to save a model and load it into a different session, but I am having prediction inconsistencies, and I would appreciate any help that can be offered. So here is what I did...

First, after running the model, I used this code to save the model:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(clf, "models.pkl")
```

and then to load the file in a different colaboratory notebook, I used the function

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
loaded_model = joblib.load('models.pkl')
```

then the program I used to process a single image for testing

```
img_toArray = cv2.imread("/content/ESD/ESD/folder1/img1.png")
new_array = cv2.resize(img_toArray, (220, 220))
new_array = np.array(new_array).reshape(1,145200)
```

but this results in an output of array([4]) with every image I test, and I am not sure why.

I have also tried to reload the entire dataset again and separate the labels from the features (the image), and use train_test_split to dedicate 90% of the dataset for testing, and when I run the features (images) to test with, through the block of code:

```
loaded_model.predict(np.array(xTest[whatEverNumber]).reshape(1,145200))
```

I get the right predictions. So I am confused as to what I a doing wrong, because in both examples,I am processing the images in basically the same method, and then separating the images and running them through the same prediction method. So I would appreciate any help in figuring out what I did wrong.

Extra information that may prove beneficial: I am using colaboratory and my model is an sklearn SVM that runs through a cross_validation_predict, cross_validation_predict, and finally an SVM fit function.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Is `loaded_model` always trained with the same data? you might be encountering this problem because your fitted model is trained with different chunks (folds) of your dataset and you are fitting/saving it with the last iteration only and hence, each time you test it, the model learns from different data (given by each fold) and returns different predictions. This if model fitting is within your cross-validation loop. May I ask, what type of train-test split did you use? shuffled?